# cannot helm install rabbitmq servers (helm 2.16.9) : namespaces "rabbit" is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

```
helm install --name my-rabbitserver stable/rabbitmq --namespace rabbit

Error: release my-rabbitserver failed: namespaces "rabbit" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "rabbit"
```

I have tried with (and without a rabbit namespace created before the install attempt)
I am using helm 2.16.9, so I need to qualify the name of my installation with a `--name`

I am using this against a Google Cloud kubernetes cluster

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7784

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the Helm tiller pod did not have sufficient priveldeges.
I found this similar issue:
https://support.sumologic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037704393-Kubernetes-Helm-install-fails-with-Error-namespaces-sumologic-is-forbidden-User-system-serviceaccount-kube-system-default-cannot-get-resource-namespaces-in-API-group-in-the-namespace-sumologic-

Basically I have to stop the tiller deployment, set up tiller ServiceAccount yaml and run it to give tiller access to the kube-system. And then execute helm init again with the new service account.
The helm rabbitmq installs then appear work as advertised

I thought helm was supposed to make life easier, but it still has its own limitations and additional yaml files to get it to work as advertised.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to Helm3? This eliminates the need for Tiller and is a more secure way of managing charts.

Comment: The helm download site, appeeared to have depreciated Helm version 3,  due to some issue, and offered 2.6 instead.

Comment: Helm3 is not deprecated at the moment.
Here is an easy way to install it `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 | bash`